# Kong Api's and Plugins are getting removed after kong docker container start and stop

Tags: docker, kong

I am trying with Kong. Iam running this on AWS.  Whenever I stop the server and start it every entry in the APIs and Plugins will go. so after each and evry start and stop I have to re-add the values for api and plugins. Can any one tell me how can I retain the data ?

docker run -d --name kong-database -p 9042:9042 cassandra:2.2 then I ran the image for kong
docker run -d --name kong --link kong-database:kong-database 
-e KONG_DATABASE=cassandra" -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database"
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" -p 8000:8000 -p 8443:8443 -p 8001:8001
-p 7946:7946 -p 7946:7946/udp kong

please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution. the steps which I did
1. take the snapshot of the cassandra keyspace using nodetool.
2. copy the snapshot of the tables which you want to restore
3. copy the snapshot to the tables of destination server
4. refresh the tables using nodetool
5. refresh the kong url , you can see the data updated there.